# save visual studio state

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there any way to save the "state" of VS 2008 (i.e. open windows, breakpoints, bookmarks, etc.) without closing it?  The pain point I'm facing is that VS 2008 crashes on me on a fairly frequent basis (every few days) and when I bring it up I've lost all my "state".  Save All does not do this... it just saves file contents.

Comment: perhaps you should put some effort in determining why "VS 2008 crashes every few days". Do you have faulty RAM? I mean VS2008 does crash but not all that often....

Comment: After I upgraded to XP SP3, I noticed some odd crashes of VS2008.  Every time I tried to move a floating window; properties, toolbox, etc., VS2008 would crash when I closed it and not save the new state.  I fooled around with docking and undocking the windows and for some reason that seemed to help.  Hasn't crashed since, but I don't really understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i do and it seems to work for me,

- Open a single instance of visual studio.
- Set all the window positions as you
  would want them.
- Close visual studio.
- From now any instance you open should
  follow those settings.

It get a bit messy when you have multiple windows open and change some settings on one of them and other setting on the other one. the key is to have a single window open when you are making your personalization and close it as soon as you are done.

Comment: I know I can save it by closing but I want to be able to make changes and save without closing or have it just remember

Comment: That would definitely be a lot more elegant, but don't know if its possible.

Answer (score 1):

Tools->Import/Export will only save the environment settings (font colors, window layout, etc).

What you should look at is Tools->Options->Environment->AutoRecover

This won't give you a button to push to save your "state" but it should do everything you were looking for automatically.

When studio crashes, usually the autorecover wizard should pop up when you restart it.

If not, the files are backed up in ...\My Documents\Visual Studio \Backup Files\.

Comment: I checked AutoRecover and it was already turned on to save every 5 minutes.  But I still don't get my open windows, breakpoints, bookmarks, etc.  Maybe AutoRecover only saves file contents?

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you have your *solution*.**[suo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx)** or *project*.csproj.**user** files under version control?

Both of these file types should not be version controlled, e.g. in Subversion you would set svn:ignore property for *.suo and *.user file types in the directory they belong to.

I believe they hold your workspace state info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much of this information will be saved but Tools Import / Exports settings will save a great deal of state in visual studio if you export everything.  It's not a quick button click process though so it may be a bit heavy weight for what you're looking for.