# How to Save State in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: tabs, dialog, state, visual-studio-2022

This is in many ways, but not entirely 100% a [dupe of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074802/save-visual-studio-state). It was asked 14 years ago and I was wondering if there'd been any '*improvement*'. [This post is about saving files not state.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71062335/auto-save-in-visual-studio-2022)

**Description of  Visual Studio 2022 previous state:** I was doing some fairly complicated work unraveling a MACRO in a million line project in  Visual Studio, had some split screens open with 5-6 different pieces of code/files, C++ header files, C++ source files etc, with *Git Changes, Solution Explorer,Output,Find Symbol Results, Error List and Find and Replace* **pinned and auto hid** around the window/workspace.

I'd 'saved' this setup using *Save Window Layout* (and here's where my mistake may have been) checked that it'd been saved, by looking at the name it was saved under, and then restarted  Visual Studio and everything I'd had open with all the current information in each toolbar/tab persisted.

Thus I thought I would just be able to go back to that 'state' via *apply window layout*.

I then clicked on the 'master' solution (there are 14 solutions) to build it, everything disappeared,(files closed, toolbars and dialog boxes emptying), and now when I apply window layout, I get all my tabs back, but there's nothing in them (they're all blank).

None of the answers in the post from 14 years ago worked; I thought `Tools->Import/Export` might be it, but no.

**The possible *'improvement'***: Is there someway of saving  Visual Studio 2022 state, so that when a solution is built/clicked on/ or some other change in state  Visual Studio 2022 is **exactly** the same as it was before (or as near as can be expected, I'm not expecting internal variables to be the same etc.).
If screenshot was taken before and after there'd be no difference, Find Symbol Results would have all the same info in it, all the files that were open would be open again, caret in the same place at the same line number etc. etc. Perhaps this isn't possible, maybe there's something I've missed ?

**Finally** On **SO** I've searched through three pages of 'Visual Studio 2022 save' and 'Visual Studio 2022 state' and done a similar amount of googling along similar lines, and only came up with the aforementioned question(s).

Comment: Is it me or has google gone very weird over the last 2 years, it barely seems to work ?

Comment: Always the way, post a question on SO and as soon as you post it, the next thing that happens is you find an answer or at least a partial one! @kay.one says (on post 14 years ago) **approximately**: just close and open, I did and got all my open files back, nothing however in *Find Symbol Results* and it feels a bit risky, if I make some changes I can't go back, only the latest state persists..

Comment: Some of the MS resources I checked out too: [Options Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-dialog-box-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) [Auto Recover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/autorecover-environment-options-dialog-box?view=vs-2022)

Comment: You can try https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ContextKeeper.ContextKeeperVsix

Comment: @SergeyVlasov, looks promising !